# Question about a sentence placement question from TOEFL Reading

Tags: exam-questions

I'm currently practicing TOEFL, and I have a question about this sentence placement question in the reading section. This is the paragraph in question ([source](https://toeflmocks.com)):

> [1](https://toeflmocks.com)Before 1815 manufacturing in the United States had been done in
> homes or shops by skilled artisans. [A] As master craftworkers, they
> imparted the knowledge of their trades to apprentices and journeymen.
> [B] In addition, women often worked in their homes part-time, making
> finished articles from raw material supplied by merchant capitalists.
> [C] After 1815 this older form of manufacturing began to give way to
> factories with machinery tended by unskilled or semiskilled laborers.
> [D] Cheap transportation networks, the rise of cities, and the
> availability of capital and credit all stimulated the shift to factory
> production.

I need to place the following sentence in one of the options:

This new form of manufacturing depended on the movement of goods to distant locations and a centralized source of laborers.

I thought the right answer should be C but it is D. Doesn't the sentence make more sense if it's placed in [C]?

Answer (score 1):

Well, till C the writer is describing the old way of production. It is only after C that the writer begins to talk about the new form of production.  The sentence to be placed talks about some new form of production and so must be placed at D.